# C# Synchronous web API call not waiting for execution to complete

Tags: c#, api, synchronous

I'm hoping someone might be able to help point me in the right direction.

I have the following synchronous call to a 3rd party API (returns void). 
The API call is used to create a new document feed and then the following code is used to select the newly created feed and return a reference.

The problem is that after making the call to the method the execution does not wait for it to finish before continuing to the search which results in a null exception. My current hack to get it to work is a 1 second sleep but I'm trying to find a better way to do it.

```
// CREATES A NEW DOCUMENT FEED
client.RegisterLCMFeed(feedName, feedName, description, defaultEntryExpiration, isEnabled, downloadOnlyOnDemand, downloadOnlyOnWiFi, sessionId);

// HACK TO DELAY THE SEARCH - NEED A REAL FIX
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

// GETS THE FEEDS FOR A SPECIFIC USER
var feeds = client.GetFeeds(sessionId);

// LOOPS THROUGH THE FEEDS AVAILABLE TO FIND THE NEW FEED
foreach (var feed in feeds)
{
  if (feed.RawId.Equals(feedName))
  {
    selectedFeed = feed;
  }
}

... 
return selectedFeed; // NULL
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Charles

Comment: If its a synchronous call and its non blocking the must be a completed event you can subscribe too, surely. But in that case its not synchronous at all? any documentation for the API?

Comment: If I have to do this, I will use preferably webAPI ( thats asynchronous and take advantage of content negotiation) Or If still you dont want to change framework , just use JQuery ( and your C# Synchronous service ) I am sure you can achieve the effect as you required